# How to create a pie chart using matplotlib from csv

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, pie-chart

Tried to follow tutorials and answers on here but couldnt wrap my head around creating a pie chart based on my data from a csv. sample of my csv below

```
    post_id post_title  subreddit   polarity    subjectivity sentiment
0   bo7h4z  ['league']  soccer       -0.2             0.4    negative
1   bnvieg  ['césar']   soccer         0               0     neutral
2   bnup5q  ['foul']    soccer        0.1             0.6    positive
3   bnul4u  ['benfica'] soccer        0.45            0.5    positive
4   bnthuf  ['prediction']  soccer     0               0     neutral
5   bnolhc  ['revolution' ] soccer     0               0     neutral
```

There are many more rows but I need to plot the sentiment column, basically how many rows are positive, neutral or negative

```
outfile = open("clean_soccer.csv","r", encoding='utf-8')
file=csv.reader(outfile)
next(file, None)

post_id = []
post_title = []
subreddit = []
polarity =[]
subjectivity = []
sentiment = []

for row in file:
    post_id.append(row[0])
    post_title.append(row[1])
    subreddit.append(row[2])
    polarity.append(row[3])
    subjectivity.append(row[4])
    sentiment.append(row[5])

plt.pie( , labels=)
plt.axis('equal') 
plt.show()
```

Would it be something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a brief answer by only reading in the `sentiment` column. You need `split` to access the sentiment column using the index `[5]`. Then, you can use `Counter` to compute the frequency and then use the values to plot the percentage in pie chart.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

outfile = open("clean_soccer.csv","r", encoding='utf-8')
file=csv.reader(outfile)
next(file, None)

sentiment = []

for row in file:
    sentiment.append(row[0].split()[5])

counts = Counter(sentiment[:-1])
plt.pie(counts.values(), labels=counts.keys(), autopct='%1.1f%%',)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Answering your second question in the comments below

```
df['sentiment'].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%',)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this gives me an error `sentiment.append(row[0].split()[5])
IndexError: list index out of range` , the file goes up to 1824 rather than 5 so i changed that but still unsuccessful `entiment.append(row[0].split()[1024])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @plshelpme_: Count the number of columns in your file. If there are `n` columns, the last column in accessed using `n-1` index because the indexing starts from 0 in python

Comment: Thank you for your help found an alternative solution (edited in my post) any idea how to display the percentages using this method?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('clean_soccer.csv')
df['sentiment'].value_counts().plot.pie()

plt.show()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56152451/3) to the question [How to create a pie chart using matplotlib from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152451/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-using-matplotlib-from-csv) by the OP [plshelpme_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11496197/plshelpme) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>